Understanding Mailbox Folder Permissions: Default vs. Anonymous Users and Issues with External Sharing
I'm working with mailbox folder permissions and have encountered some confusion regarding user types and external sharing. Specifically, I have two types of user permissions for a mailbox folder:
Default: This is used for people within the organization.
Anonymous: This seems to be used for external access.
I understand that the Default permission is for users inside the organization, but I’m not clear on the exact purpose of the Anonymous permission. What does it do, and in what scenarios is it used?
Additionally, I’m facing an issue where external sharing for a mailbox folder is not working. Despite configuring permissions for external users, they are unable to access the folder. What could be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it?
error image
